# SQL Get subtotal in each group

Tags: sql, group-by, sap-ase, subtotal

Good Morning in my timezone

My goal is :

```
TYPE |  CODE | PRICE | QUANTITY
A       10      34       1
A       11      20       2
A       15      17       2
A       Total   71       5
B       13      14       1
B       10      24       2
B      Total    38       3
```

I am using Sybase ASE version 15.5 so there is not the ROLLUP or CUBE operators.
Is the cursor the only way i got ?

Thanks in advance
Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use such a SQL statement with `union all` ( *ordering is important for your aim* ):

```
select q.*
  from
  (
    select type, cast(code as char(5)) as code, price, quantity
      from tab
    union all
    select type, 'Total', sum(price), sum(quantity) 
      from tab
    group by type
  ) q
  order by type, code
```

I'm a adding a [***Demo***](https://rextester.com/LNNWFK23905) in *SQL Server* but syntax works for both.